# Como alterar não apenas o estilo mas o formato da célula com C# usando NPOI?

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel, npoi

quando eu gero um arquivo no Excel utilizando a biblioteca **NPOI** (https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi/tree/master/examples/xssf) eu consigo alterar o estilo da célula para **moneyFormat** com o código a seguir, entretanto, quando o usuário abre o Excel as células estão com o **formatação de "GERAL"** e para que ele consiga, por exemplo, somar todas as transações selecionando as células, ele precisa apertar **F2** (editar célula) e apertar **Enter**, só então a célula muda de formato. Alguém sabe como resolver isso? Segue o código:

```cs
HSSFFont boldFont = (HSSFFont)workBook.CreateFont();  
HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = (HSSFCellStyle)workBook.CreateCellStyle();  

ICellStyle moneyFormat = workBook.CreateCellStyle();  
ICellStyle percentFormat = workBook.CreateCellStyle();  
ICellStyle qtdFormat = workBook.CreateCellStyle();  

//Define máscaras  
IDataFormat format = workBook.CreateDataFormat();  
moneyFormat.DataFormat = format.GetFormat("R$#,##0.00");  
percentFormat.DataFormat = format.GetFormat("0.00");  
qtdFormat.DataFormat = format.GetFormat("0");  

//Linhas  
foreach (var linha in mvtFinanceiroList)  
{  
    row = (HSSFRow)sheet.CreateRow(index);  
    row.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue(linha.tb_ban_banco.ban_c_descricao); //Cria 1ª coluna da 1ª linha  

    int lastRow1 = row.LastCellNum;  
    row.CreateCell(lastRow1).SetCellValue(linha.mvt_c_descricao); //Cria 2ª coluna da 1ª linha  

    int lastRow2 = row.LastCellNum;  
    row.CreateCell(lastRow2).SetCellValue(string.Format("{0:C}", linha.mvt_n_valor)); //Cria 3ª coluna da 1ª linha  
    row.GetCell(lastRow2).CellStyle = moneyFormat; //Aplica máscara de Grana  

    int lastRow3 = row.LastCellNum;  
    row.CreateCell(lastRow3).SetCellValue(linha.mvt_d_dataMovimento.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));  
    row.GetCell(lastRow3).CellStyle = cellStyleCenter; //Posiciona no centro  

    index++;  
}
```

Comment: não seria o `SetDataFormat()` no `CellStyle`?

Comment: Leandro Angelo, não deu certo. Tentei diversas variações de SetDataFormat(), porém sem efeito.

Comment: O mais próximo que cheguei foi vendo esse tutorial, mas também não funciona corretamente para valor em reais. [link](https://forums.asp.net/t/1587430.aspx?NPOI+Excel+number+format+not+showing+in+Excel+sheet+in+asp+net)

Answer (score 1):

Acabei conseguindo resolver. Era mais simples do que parecia. Para dar certo no Excel o correto é converter para Double ao invés de decimal (¬¬)

```cs
HSSFFont boldFont = (HSSFFont)workBook.CreateFont();  
HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = (HSSFCellStyle)workBook.CreateCellStyle();  

ICellStyle moneyFormat = workBook.CreateCellStyle();  
ICellStyle percentFormat = workBook.CreateCellStyle();  
ICellStyle qtdFormat = workBook.CreateCellStyle();  

//Define máscaras  
IDataFormat format = workBook.CreateDataFormat();  
moneyFormat.DataFormat = format.GetFormat("R$#,##0.00");  
percentFormat.DataFormat = format.GetFormat("0.00");  
qtdFormat.DataFormat = format.GetFormat("0");  

//Linhas  
foreach (var linha in mvtFinanceiroList)  
{  
    row = (HSSFRow)sheet.CreateRow(index);  
    row.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue(linha.tb_ban_banco.ban_c_descricao); //Cria 1ª coluna da 1ª linha  

    int lastRow1 = row.LastCellNum;  
    row.CreateCell(lastRow1).SetCellValue(linha.mvt_c_descricao); //Cria 2ª coluna da 1ª linha  

    int lastRow2 = row.LastCellNum;  
    row.CreateCell(lastRow2).SetCellValue(Convert.ToDouble(linha.mvt_n_valor)); //Cria 3ª coluna da 1ª linha  
    row.GetCell(lastRow2).CellStyle = moneyFormat; //Aplica máscara de Grana  

    int lastRow3 = row.LastCellNum;  
    row.CreateCell(lastRow3).SetCellValue(linha.mvt_d_dataMovimento.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));  
    row.GetCell(lastRow3).CellStyle = cellStyleCenter; //Posiciona no centro  

    index++;  
}
```